# An Evil Vector Problem!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

> A person is walking on straight road starting with a velocity $v$, the direction of of air ,observed by him makes an angle $\alpha$ with his is direction of motion. Now during the race, he finds direction of air rotates by angle $\alpha$ at a uniform rotating rate. It is given that air is flowing perpendicular to track. Find length of the track.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: But it's my doubt, not a homework

Comment: A complete problem is your doubt ? !! Show some effort brother and present some working ! It's saves the time of the person answering and displays how much you worked on the problem -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ the angle the air speed makes with the person

$\omega$ the uniform angular speed

$t = \alpha/\omega$ the time of the race

$vt$ the length of the road, because air friction is considered negligible

Comment: Can't we approach this problem by integration

Comment: When you walk does the wind modify your walk? Ask yourself this, if your answer is yes then you can use this integration.